# rearrangement of infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to find a justification why it is correct to write for any non negative sequence $(a_{n,m})_{n,m} \subset \mathbb{R}$ that

$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij} $$
is always true (even if$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} = \infty$).

I found in the book Analysis I of Ahmann & Escher that if

$$  \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{j,k=1}^n |a_{jk}| < \infty$$ holds, then for any bijective map $\alpha : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ it holds

$$  \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{\alpha(n)} =  \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij} < \infty.$$

But how can I see that if 
$$  \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{j,k=1}^n |a_{jk}| = \infty$$ holds, that
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij} $$
remains if $a_{ij} \geq 0$?

Comment: Your first equality is always true. There is nothing to do...May be you meant $\sum_i \sum_j a_{ij}=\sum_j \sum_i a_{ij}$.

Comment: @user37238 ofc your right..

Comment: By $ \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{j,k=0}^n |a_{jk}|$,you mean $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n |a_{jk}|$ right? (The indexes don't start everywhere the same)...

Comment: @Surb yes thanks for the note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the way the cases are split is according to whether the sequence of the sum of 'initial segments' of the elements in the 2d sequence is unbounded. If not, then you get the first part as you mentioned. If there is, then whichever order you take the sum it will eventually exceed any arbitrary amount.

Rigorously:

For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$:

Let $n$ be such that $\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n {a_i}_j \ge x$

Then $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty {a_i}_j \ge \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^\infty {a_i}_j \ge \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^n {a_i}_j \ge x$ because all the limits exist

Therefore $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty {a_i}_j = \infty$

Likewise $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^\infty {a_i}_j = \infty$

So in fact it is the other case that is more tricky.